# Makefile Linking with shared library fails

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I was trying to write a shared library and trying to link it to form the final executable.

Makefile

```
mystring.out:main.c libmystring.so
    gcc -I. -L/home/pradheep/myexploration/mystring/ -lmystring main.c -o mystring.out

libmystring.so:mystring.o
    gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmystring.so -o libmystring.so mystring.o

libmystring.a:mystring.o
    ar -r libmystring.a mystring.o

mystring.o:mystring.h mystring.c
    gcc -Wall -g -c -fPIC -I. mystring.c

clean:
    rm *.o 
    rm *.a
    rm *.so
    rm *.out
```

Here is the Error message:

```
 gcc -I. -L/home/pradheep/myexploration/mystring/ -lmystring  main.c -o mystring.out
 /tmp/ccS9UDPS.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `mystrcpy'
main.c:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `mystrncpy'
main.c:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `mystrncpy'
main.c:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `mystrlen'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mystring.out] Error 1
```

I have already exported the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/pradheep/myexploration/mystring
```

Output of my libmystring.so

```
 000004ca T mystrncpy
 0000045c T mystrcpy
```

What am i missing ?

Solution:

The problem was the order of the library -l usage. It should be used after the source file 
and the correct order as pointed out by Dayal rai is 
gcc -I. -L/home/pradheep/myexploration/mystring/   main.c -lmystring -o mystring.out
and hurray it works.

Comment: Have u included mystring.h in main.c file ?

Comment: yes i have added it ... Infact the same is working in command line

Comment: @Omkant Header files have nothing to do with linker errors. What matters is the place of the `-lmystring` linker flag.

Comment: IOW, does it link with the following changed line in the Makefile? `gcc -I. -L/home/pradheep/myexploration/mystring/ main.c -lmystring -o mystring.out`

Comment: note to self for future. Ask in SO before breaking your head for 2 days :P

Comment: @Pradheep That is not a good note.You may get thousands of downvotes on your question if it won't have efforts from your side.

Comment: @Dayalrai i had all the above for the past 2 days but i was not able to do anything.Yes. I would put in my effort and when struck with a wall i will sure to seek out help here. Maybe 2 days is a good time frame when i cannot crack it to seekout help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The traditional behaviour of linkers is to search for external functions from left to right in the libraries specified on the command line. This means that a library containing the definition of a function should appear after any source files or object files which use it.

Comment: you are spot on. I did not know the same. Changing the rule to gcc -I. -L/home/pradheep/myexploration/mystring/   main.c -lmystring     -o mystring.out did the trick .I never knew i was making this silly mistake.Will update in the question too

Comment: I have added a new section so that the answer is obvious the someone looking for the same :) Thanks